# PostgreSQL suddently takes all the disk space

Tags: postgresql

I am facing a very strange issue on my server, my configuration is very straight-forward:

- Small VPS, 500 MiB RAM, 40 GiB disk
- Debian stable at install time, now probably old_stable
- PostgreSQL v11.11

The data is very small, the use of a database for my purpose is probably overkill, but handy:

- 7 tables
- 7 views, including one of them which is a little bit scary
- The biggest table have a few hundred records
- The full dump of the database gives me a file of 93 KiB

Everything was very fast for 1.5 year. Yesterday, the database suddenly became very slow. My investigations showed that the size of *the data on the disk was 34 GiB* and I had no disk space available anymore.

After more investigations, I tried the command "vacuum full", which deleted the useless 34 GiB. The disk space changed from 100% usage to 10% usage and the performances came back immediately. One day later, the system is slow again, I saw the disk usage is now around 50%.

I have no clue about what is going on, any suggestion?

Comment: If `VACUUM (FULL)` helps, something is bloating your tables. Could be a workload with lots of updates, could be [one of these problems](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/).

Comment: The updates are also infrequent, maybe 5 times a month. The data is also ridiculously small. Is it possible that an un-optimized views create many duplicated stuff in the background to get good performance?

Comment: No, not at all. Since you seem to have little experience with PostgreSQL and don't even know how to investigate this and have no leads, I don't think that anybody's crystal ball is good enough to divine the reason and provide you with a useful answer. If I were you, I'd have a PostgreSQL consultant take a look at it.

Comment: You probably have a roque process doing things it shouldn't do. A tiny database like this that does a handful of updates a month, can never ever result in dozens of gigabytes of disk space. Something is destroying your database. Use pg_stat_activity and of course your log files, to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading [Optimize and Improve PostgreSQL Performance with VACUUM, ANALYZE, and REINDEX](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/optimize-and-improve-postgresql-performance-with-vacuum-analyze-and-reindex-885239781.html) and [Routine Vacuuming](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html). Here's some relevant bits.

> In normal PostgreSQL operation, tuples that are deleted or obsoleted by an update are not physically removed from their table

You must have done *a lot* of deletes and updates, so Postgres consumed a lot of disk space. [`vacuum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html) recovers this space. `vacuum full` isn't normally necessary and will lock your database.

Normally there is an [autovacuum daemon](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) running which will `vacuum` periodically. It probably isn't running. Check with `show autovacuum` and `show track_counts`. Both need to be true for autovacuum to run.

You can see what is "bloating" your database with the [`check_postgres`](https://bucardo.org/check_postgres/check_postgres.pl.html#bloat) tool.